# exec sp_addrole 'db_accessamin','user_name';

Tags: sql, database

Can someone explain this query to me. I'm a student and getting confused after read this query. please someone explain this in detail in simple English. thank you!

Comment: [sp_addrole](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addrole-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

> exec sp_addrole 'db_accessamin','user_name';

`exec` is the shorthand way to write `Execute` so you are executing the function `sp_addrole` which adds a new role to your current database.  That role is `db_accessamin` which may be meant to say `db_accessadmin`?  And the `user_name` is the owner of the new role, typically defaulting to the user executing the function.

Basically, this is giving yourself a new role in whatever database you're working on.